# Problem with toolstrip renderer in VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I'm using the toolstrip renderer in vb.net, found the source over at:
http://63.236.73.220/showthread.php?t=539578

Now, it works great however the style doesn't seem to stick when I click a button on the toolbar. I use a toolstrip sort of like tabs, and what I'd like is if a toolstrip menu is clicked the style stays so I can visually see what tab is clicked.

Can someone help me out with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue... Turns out the default toolstrip renderer supports the clicked item state, so I had to turn on the "checkonclick" to true and then when the the toolstrip button is clicked it shows the selected state, then in the code on the click event I did a loop to uncheck all other buttons in the toolstrip so now it functions exactly like a tab interface using the fancy toolstrip renderer :)